# Oracle Timestamp fails at condition

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp

I have table `systemproperties`, which stores `propertyname (varchar)` and `propertyvalue (clob)`. Under that one of the properties are,

```
propertyname - RowDate
propertyvalue - 12-MAY-17 04.00.06.883000 PM
```

And another table `activity`, I am storing the log data with `timestamp(6)`.

Query to fetch log data from `activity` table,

```
select type,startdate from activity where startdate > ?
```

Here `startdate` is `timestamp(6)` type. I am using the actual value and the  results are nothing. But, if I use as below:

```
select type,startdate from activity 
where startdate > (select to_char(propertyvalue) 
                   from systemproperties where propertyname='RowDate')
```

I am getting the rows greater than the time. I am unable to understand the difference here. Could any one guide me here. What can I use for the solution?

Here are my NLS Settings:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_SORT            BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT     HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your property is defined like this:

```
propertyvalue - 12-MAY-17 04.00.06.883000 PM
```

Now you think that means 12th May 2017 but that's not what you've said. So when casting the string `12-MAY-17 04.00.06.883000 PM` to a date Oracle does what it usually does, and defaults the century to `00`.

Demo:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
2017-05-14 23:50:09

SQL> select to_date('17-05-14 00:00:00') my_date from dual;

MY_DATE
-------------------
0017-05-14 00:00:00

SQL>
```

That's why you get the results you do. Obviously you have a lot of records where `startdate > date '0017-05-12'`

> "What can I use for the solution?"

The best solution is to define the date properly. It is **2017** and that's way too late to still be coding the Y2K bug.

```
propertyvalue - 12-MAY-2017 04.00.06.883000 PM
```

Alternatively you can use an explicit date mask when you reference the property:

```
startdate > to_date(propertyvalue, 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF6 AM')
```

In this case Oracle will substitute the current century `20` for the missing element of the mask. It's still a bug waiting to happen but `20` is more likely to be the right answer more often than `00`.

---

> "startdate is a timestamp(6)"

Doesn't matter, Oracle treats them both the same in this respect:

```
SQL> alter table t23 add ts timestamp;

Table altered.

SQL> update t23 set ts = systimestamp;

4 rows updated.

SQL> select count(*) from t23 where ts > to_date('17-05-16 00:00:00');

  COUNT(*)
----------
         4

SQL> select count(*) from t23 where ts > to_date('17-05-16 00:00:00', 'yy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL>
```

Comment: I tried the same in my machine, but the sysdate format varies here, `SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
---------
15-MAY-17`

Comment: fyi... `startdate` is a `timestamp(6)`. so as per you comment, oracle tries to cast it to `date` or `timestamp`

Comment: I have amended my answer to show how you can change the displayed date format.

Comment: That explains clearly. One more clarification , `startdate > '12-MAY-2017 04.00.06.883000 PM'` ,takes **25s** to retrieve 4 records where `startdate > to_char('12-MAY-2017 04.00.06.883000 PM')` takes **2s**.

Comment: Given that `startdate` is a timestamp why are you casting the property to a string rather than a date data type?

Comment: I did not want to, but via program, i just set a string while executing the query. `statement.setString(1,"12-MAY-17 04.00.06.883000 PM");`. I just gave it a try.

Answer (score 1):

When you compare `startdate > your_property_string`, Oracle will implicitly try to convert the property string to a matching data type (i.e. `TIMESTAMP`) using the appropriate `NLS_SESSION` parameter as the format mask. So the `WHERE` clause will be implicitly converted to the equivalent of:

```
WHERE startdate > TO_TIMESTAMP(
                    your_property_string,
                    ( SELECT value
                      FROM   SYS.NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
                      WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT' )
                  )
```

So, Oracle can give different values for your property string depending on what your `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` is set to. I.e. if it is `YYYY-MON-DD HH12:MI:SS.FF6 AM` then your date would be parsed as `0015-05-17T16:00:06.883000` and if it was `DD-MON-YY HH12:MI:SS.FF6 AM` then it would be `2017-05-15T16:00:06.883000`.

If you want to be consistent when converting the string then you will have to explicitly specify the format mask in the query (and the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`):

```
SELECT type,
       startdate
FROM   activity 
WHERE  startdate > TO_TIMESTAMP(
                     ?,
                     'DD-MON-YY HH12.MI.SS.FF6 AM',
                     'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'
                   )
```

Comment: For Executing this `SELECT value
                      FROM   SYS.NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
                      WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT'`, I got this, `DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM`

Comment: @ArockiaRaj The big issue with using the implicit conversion is that the `NLS` settings are session parameters and **any** user can change them in their own session and this would break the query without the query having changed.

Comment: @ArockiaRaj What is the value and data type of the bind parameter being passed into your original `select type,startdate from activity where startdate > ?` query?

Comment: value - `12-MAY-17 04.00.06.883000 PM` , data type - `clob` which is present on the systemproperties table. via program, `? -> stmt.setString(1, "12-MAY-17 04.00.06.883000 PM")`